# How to get Karma to run these test files?

Tags: karma-runner

I'm new to automated testing. I'm trying to run some tests inside my IDE, WebStorm. It seems to support jsTestDriver and Karma. As I understand it, JsTestDriver doesn't natively support RequireJS, which [these tests](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js/blob/master/spec/date.spec.js) need.

Karma, however, [says it does](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/plus/requirejs.html). I've created a test file,

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'spec/*.spec.js', included: false},
        ],
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9885,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        captureTimeout: 10000,
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

But it just seems to hang after it outputs this (running from node terminal):

```
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\GitHub\timezone-js>karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.1 server started at http://localhost:9885/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket id MYUP0uo-jk-3W8hB8trx
```

If I run it in a browser and check the JavaScript console, I get this:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined  
http://localhost:9878/base/spec/date.spec.js  
Line 1
```

Why is it complaining about "require" if Karma supports it and I included it as one of the frameworks..?

Answer (score 7):

**Check out [the docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/plus/requirejs.html).**

You are missing some `test-main.js` file, where you configure Require.js and kick off the test run by requiring something (probably all of your tests).